# How to create Flip Page View on android?

Tags: flip

How can I create flip page view on android like iOS with .pdf file

Answer (score 1):

You can try FlexPaper, it supports Android and iOS

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/examples/usecases/Whitepapers/Whitepaper_html5_pdf_sample.jsp

Comment: Your product does appear to be relevant to the question, but you need to disclose that you are affiliated with the publisher.

Comment: Is there any example for using this brilliant in an android application?